# Angular + SVG: how to dynamically load template from string

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, svg

In Angular, it's possible to use SVG as component template. I wonder if there is a way to convert a SVG content (string loaded from server) into a component template, including the possibility to bind some properties to it (i.e, `<tspan [attr.color]="textColor" ...>{{myText}}</tspan>`).

I've made some tests and all that I got was to load and render the SVG content, but the binds are not working. Instead, they are rendered as strings.

I know that if put the SVG content in a file and reference it in component's `templateUrl` setting, it works. For example:

```js
...
@Component({
   templateUrl: './content.svg'
})
export class MyComponent {
   ...
}
...
```

I've already tested it. However, I need to load the SVG from a server (it cannot be a static file or hard coded in source-code).

Can anyone help me?

### Update

Just to clarify a little bit...

Consider the following component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `<div [innerHtml]="mySvg"></div>`
})
export class MyComponent {
    textColor: string;
    myText: string;
    mySvg: string;

    constructor() {
        this.textColor = '#ff0000';
        this.myText = 'Just testing';
    }

    loadSvg() {
        // here goes some logic to request the SVG string from server
        // ...
       this.mySvg = response;
    }
}
```

Now, consider that the server returned the following string:

```xml
<svg>
    <tspan [attr.color]="textColor">{{myText}}</tspan>
</svg>
```

I would like the SVG to be rendered and the interpolations to work as well (making it possible to change the text and color).

Is it possible?

Comment: You have to parse your string as a **tagged template**; see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. But I think that the solution is more complex than that, because the SVG content comes from server and is not hardcoded or placed in a static file. I gave some details, to clarify my needs.

Comment: I found this angular library https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks, but I still didn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to native **standard Javascript template literal** notation: **${x}**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
 `string ${property} string string ${property} string`
```

You can create a **tagged template function** that does all the replacing of property values for you

Here the **template string** is the `innerHTML`, properties as attributes

**When you make up your own template syntax (or use 3rd party)** You will have to add a lot more boilerplate code or libraries to **parse that String**

```html
<svg-from-template cx="30" cy="30">
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='${bgcolor}'></rect>
  <circle cx='${cx}' cy='${cy}' r='10%' fill='${fill}'></circle>
</svg-from-template>
<svg-from-template bgcolor="lightgreen" cx="70" cy="70" fill="green">
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='${bgcolor}'></rect>
  <circle cx='${cx}' cy='${cy}' r='20%' fill='${fill}'></circle>
</svg-from-template>
<script>
  customElements.define(
    "svg-from-template",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        function parseTemplate(templateString, templateData = {}) {
          return new Function( // create Function AND return the executed function result
            "templateProps", [
              "let f = ( " + Object.keys(templateData).join(",") + " ) =>",
              "`" + templateString + "`",
              "return f(...Object.values(templateProps))",
            ].join("\n")
          )(templateData); // execute tagged template function
        }
        setTimeout(() => { // wait till all innerHTML is parsed by the Browser
          let templateData = [...this.attributes].reduce((acc, attr) => {
            acc[attr.name] = attr.value; // copy element attributes to {} object
            return acc;
          }, { /*default object*/ bgcolor: 'pink', fill: 'red' });
          let templateString = this.innerHTML; // OR read from file/server/universe
          this.innerHTML = "<svg mlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>" +
            parseTemplate(templateString, templateData) + "</svg>";
        });
      }
    }
  );
</script>
<style>
  svg {
    width: 180px;
    /* SO snippet window height */
  }
</style>
```